# heroku application error becaouse of gevent

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, gevent

when I try to push to Heroku its deploys correctly but shows application error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ktKn.png)

no updates are possible ,
log of heroku is following

> 2018-09-13T04:54:13.237927+00:00 app[web.1]:     import gevent
>
> 2018-09-13T04:54:13.237928+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/**init**.py",
>   line 41, in
>
> 2018-09-13T04:54:13.237930+00:00 app[web.1]:     from gevent.hub
>   import get_hub, iwait, wait
>
> 2018-09-13T04:54:13.237931+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line
>   289
>
> 2018-09-13T04:54:13.237932+00:00 app[web.1]:     except Exception, ex:
>
> 2018-09-13T04:54:13.237933+00:00 app[web.1]:                     ^
>
> 2018-09-13T04:54:13.237934+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: invalid
>   syntax
>
> 2018-09-13T04:54:13.237936+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
>
> 2018-09-13T04:54:13.237944+00:00 app[web.1]:

Comment: Which version of `gevent` you are using?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  You are using Python2 style try/except, which would cause the exact error you mention in a Python 3 environment. Could you include a sample of the code causing the error?

Comment: @a_python_user  gevent==1.0.2

Comment: @ARJMP  i am using python 2

Comment: amqp==1.4.9
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==3.3.0.23
boto==2.38.0
celery==3.1.0
Collectfast==0.2.3
dj-database-url==0.3.0
Django==1.8.6
django-celery==3.1.17
django-cors-headers==1.1.0
django-s3-folder-storage==0.3
django-storages==1.1.8
gevent==1.0.2
greenlet==0.4.9
gunicorn==19.4.5
kombu==3.0.37
Pillow==3.0.0
psycopg2==2.7.3.1
python-dateutil==2.4.2
pytz==2015.7
redis==2.10.3
requests==2.4.3
six==1.10.0
sparkpost==1.0.0
validate-email==1.3
vine==1.1.3
Whitenoise==4.0

Comment: @a_python_user Python 2.7.12

Comment: Do you have a `runtime.txt` file in your projects root? If so what text does it contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I see the problem, you are using Python 3 to run your Heroku application.

The line `2018-09-13T04:54:13.237931+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 289` specifically says you are using the Python 3.6 runtime, and the gevent library you are using is meant for Python 2. (The Exception is using Python 2 syntax)

Check the `runtime.txt` in your projects root folder and ensure it says "python-2.7.15", Heroku has docs on specifying the python runtime for your application https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes.